# Prevent some components inside /pages folder to become a route in NextJS

Tags: next.js

As I need an `/about` route in NextJS, I've created the following folder structure:

```
...
 |
pages/
 |
 ├── about/
       |
       ├── index.js
       |
       ├── AboutContent.jsx
```

Where `AboutContent.jsx` is just a component to help `index.js` with part of the logic. The problem is that the `AboutContent.jsx` has become a route:`/about/AboutContent`. How do I prevent non-index.js components to become routes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move it out of the `pages` folder.

`pages` folder must have only page components, rest of the components you can put in your `src` folder.

```
 |
pages/
 |
 ├── about/
       |
       ├── index.js
src/
 |
 ├── AboutContent.jsx
```

just import `AboutContent` from the `src` folder

#### Edit

in Next.js v13+ there is a new concept folder which calls `app` which allows you to have components inside it, this concept converts only the `index.js` files to routes.

Comment: I was looking for some `helpers` directory that wouldn't be a route to separate some components that do specific jobs. My problem is that i'm using React Native + React Native Web + Next JS, so if I move like SEO component that serve only for web, RN will also compile it.

Answer (score 4):

You can colocate test files or other files used by components in the pages directory. Inside next.config.js, add the pageExtensions config:

```
module.exports = {
  pageExtensions: ['page.tsx', 'page.ts', 'page.jsx', 'page.js'],
}
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-page-extensions

Comment: this is the answer. With something like this, anything that does not match the `name.page.ext` file name convention, is not a page/route

Comment: This one is the answer, thanks! To be more specific, after the next config above  you need to also rename your files you want to be page to {filename}.page.tsx so that other files inside pages directory will not be seen as pages

Comment: It would be great, if not this bug https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/32403 which totally ruins the approach.

Answer (score 0):

In **BETA** `Next.js@13.0.x`, you can move your pages and components to `/app` directory while it is still okay to keep the page components under `/pages` directory. But routes across `/app` and `/pages` directories should not resolve to the same URL path. It may cause a build-time exception. I recommend to upgrade your `Next.js` to the latest and put all pages in `/app` directory.

```
 |
app/
 |
 ├── about/
       |
       |-- AbountContent.js
       ├── layout.js
       |-- page.js

 |
ui/
 |
 |-- BaseComponent.js
```